# UPDATE with no subquery throws error: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mysql-5.6

Can somebody explain to me this... :)
(using MySQL 5.6.13)

```
UPDATE offer SET cosid=1 WHERE id=40;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

UPDATE offer SET cosid=4 WHERE id=40;
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

UPDATE offer SET cosid=5 WHERE id=40;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Every valid index is accepted except of four :(

This is offer table:

```
CREATE TABLE offer (
  id               bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  authorid         bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
  offered_designid bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
  cdid             bigint(20), 
  cosid            bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id), 
  UNIQUE INDEX (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Any suggestion what might be wrong?

EDITED: This is current cos table:

```
SELECT * FROM cos;
+----+-------------+
| id | offer_state |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | active      |
|  5 | cancelled   |
|  3 | inactive    |
|  4 | realized    |
|  2 | waiting     |
+----+-------------+
```

5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: I guess a bug could cause this. Or corrupted indexes (maybe.) I wonder why you have set both Primary and Unique index on the same column though (not that it should create this faulty behaviour, this is irrelevant question.)

Comment: Another probable cause is triggers. Do you have an UPDATE trigger on the table?

Comment: Thank you very much ypercube there was trigger on offer update, which changed states. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As ypercube has stated in the comments, and you have confirmed, triggers are the culprit here!